# Form submission in javascript disabled Browser

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a drop-down which will display the phone numbers on click of which I need to submit a form in JavaScript disabled browser.

Currently I am doing the following stuff:

```
<form action="/servlet/myservlet" method="GET">
    <select name="myselect" id="myselect" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <c:forEach items="${mydata.phoneNumbers}" var="phoneNumber">
            <option value="${phoneNumber}">${phoneNumber}</option>
            </c:forEach>
```

Or is there any way to achieve the same withe below bootstrap code with JavaScript disabled

```
<button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="prefix-num" data-toggle="dropdown"> ${mydata.phoneNumber}</button> <ul class="dropdown-menu dropmenu-menu-custom" role="menu" aria-labelledby="prefix-number-1"> <c:forEach items="${mydata.phoneNumbers}" var="phoneNumber"> <li><a href="/servlet/myservlet" class="changeNumber" role="menuitem">${phoneNumber}</a></li> </c:forEach> </ul>
```

But once I click on drop-down values form is not getting submitted.

Comment: are you want to submit the form without using javascript?

Comment: this.form.submit() not worked in JS disabled browser

Answer (score 6):

You need a `type="submit"` button to submit the form without JavaScript. There's no other way.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="/servlet/myservlet" method="POST">
    <select name="myselect" id="myselect" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <c:forEach items="${mydata.phoneNumbers}"
                                            var="phoneNumber">
                     <option value="${phoneNumber}">${phoneNumber}</option>
                                        </c:forEach>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="sub_btn" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Please add `submit button control` to submit the form without JavaScript.

Also, use `POST` method instead of `GET` otherwise your form data will get passed in query string of URL.

Comment: But i want to submit the form on click of dropdown values is that possible??

Comment: Or is there a way to achieve the same withe below bootstrap code with javascript disabled- <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button"
          id="prefix-num" data-toggle="dropdown">
          ${mydata.phoneNumber}</button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu dropmenu-menu-custom" role="menu"
          aria-labelledby="prefix-number-1">
          <c:forEach items="${mydata.phoneNumbers}"
           var="phoneNumber">
           <li><a href="/servlet/myservlet" class="changeNumber" role="menuitem">${phoneNumber}</a></li>
          </c:forEach>
         </ul>